# How to update progress Dialog text every 5sec in android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, timer, callback, progressdialog

I want change Progress dialog text dynamically every 5sec .... while syncing data tables from MySQL to sqlite ... i tried using custom class but still text not changing for every 5s .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's an example: http://huuah.com/android-progress-bar-and-thread-updating/

Comment: You should post your code and ask a more specific question, at the moment it sounds like you're searching for a completely working solution.

Comment: thnx's for quick response kirsty... i just try!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a handler with postDelayed:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void checkProgress() {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run() {
                    boolean done = false;
                    mytextView.setText("updated Text");

                    // Some logic here to check when progress is done, then flip boolean

                    if (!done) {
                        checkProgress();
                    }
               }
        }, 5000);
}
```

I didnt test any of this code but this might get you on the right track.

Comment: when i sync table1 ... i want show - "Syncing table1 ...done" similarly for 15 tables i want show update text messages ... i want change text every 5s in dialog. but runnable method () doesn't support dynamic meassage ... pls, guide me how can i proceed??

Comment: handler runs on the ui thread so you can directly change any ui elements. Also the 5000 above is a 5 second delay, this process will run every 5 seconds until the done variable is switched to true.